# How to create a dynamically allocated C++ Object and its pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory

This might be a newbie question, but I am asking myself it anyway.

If I have a `Object` class defined:

```
Object *p = new Object();
```

Does this code create a pointer `p`, and at location `p`, place a `Object` object, correct?

Comment: see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: I think the downvotes are because you don't show any research. You can find a lot of information on a lot of webpages, including wikipedia as liked by Sanish, but also in any [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1), [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) or [reference webpage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. It will ease searching for the answer for those, who come later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means:

- Prepare a variable for an address to Parent class and name it `p`
- Allocate enough memory to store contents of a Parent class
- Call the constructor of a Parent class
- Store address of that memory in variable `p`.

---

**Edit**: In response to comment:

This is not the only way to construct a class. The other one is to allocate a class statically, eg.

`Parent p;`

In such case you don't store a pointer to the Parent class in variable p, but the whole class itself. In such case:

- Memory for the class is located on the stack in a frame reserved for function, which defines this variable (stack is allocated only once, when program is loaded into memory)
- Constructor is called automatically, when program reaches point of declaration of the variable.
- Destructor is called automatically, when program leaves the scope of this variable
- No memory is deallocated (at least none for instance of Parent class), because stack is reused later.

Comment: not quite... the instance of `Parent` is also default-constructed

Comment: So I still need p = new Parent(), to actually create an instance of the class right?

Comment: i dont think the edit was required. OP was asking for Dynamic allocation. But this ans should be well enough for future ref. +1